# Duplicate entry '2' for key error in Spring jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a spring boot app where I am using JPA for all data transactions and I came across this error while using `OneToMany` relationship.

Here are both my models:

user.java

```
@Entity
public class user {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String username;

private String password;

private String role;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private file f;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(targetEntity=job.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<job> applied;


 //getters ,setters and constuctors.

    }
```

job.java

```
@Entity
public class job {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String role;
    
    private String company;
    
    private String salary;
    
    private String description;
    
    private String level;
    
    private Date expiry;
    
   private String skills;
   
   private String location;
   
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=user.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<user> candidates;

    //getters setters and constructor
    
  }
```

here's the method that triggers the error:

```
public String applyToJob(Integer userId,Integer jobId)
    {
        job jobToApply= jobRepo.getOne(jobId);
        user applier=userRepo.getById(userId);
        List<job> jobs=applier.getApplied();
        jobs.add(jobToApply);
        applier.setApplied(jobs);
        userRepo.save(applier);
        List<user> candidates=jobToApply.getCandidates();
        System.out.println(candidates);
        candidates.add(userRepo.getOne(userId));
        System.out.println(candidates);
        jobToApply.setCandidates(candidates);
        jobRepo.save(jobToApply);
        return "Job Apply Success";
        
    }
```

Now that I want to add data inside job's candidates field I get the below error:

```
2021-10-07 17:17:37.542  WARN 21696 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2021-10-07 17:17:37.543 ERROR 21696 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '2' for key 'job_candidates.UK_q0o76ghxl59c5ip3qwatsxo3f'
2021-10-07 17:17:37.543  INFO 21696 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2021-10-07 17:17:37.564 ERROR 21696 --- [nio-8090-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [job_candidates.UK_q0o76ghxl59c5ip3qwatsxo3f]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '2' for key 'job_candidates.UK_q0o76ghxl59c5ip3qwatsxo3f'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java
```

Comment: Can you please share your database schema? Did you create it or did you rely on Hibernate to do it for you?

Comment: JPA did it for me

Comment: Did you clear the database before trying again?

Comment: yes I did clear the db

Comment: Does the user returned from `userRepo.getOne(userId)` already exist in the candidates collection? The error indicates a duplicate candidate. In any case you should check to see if a candidate already exists in the candidates collection before adding it to the collection.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are adding a candidate to the job entity, which is already previously mapped to that particular job.
Please thoroughly check your entries in the DB and try to find out if there is any candidate that is being added multiple times to the same job, preferably with id as 2.
Let me know if you face any further difficulties!

Comment: this is a comment, rather than an answer